# How to do a delaunay triangulation of a circle

Tags: c++, opencv, triangulation, delaunay

does anyone knows how to create a delaunay triangulation of a circle in c++? I already have one solution but it's very efficient, I used the openCV delaunay.c as an example. I was wondering if someone had done something similar and could give-me a hint.

Comment: What's wrong with your "very efficient" solution?  Are you looking for something less efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Other Libs: CGAL, Fade2D, Triangle, ...